# Installing docker-ce through puppet

Tags: docker, puppet

Im trying to install docker-ce through puppet and i have a couple of questions.

1: Does apt::key automatically do a 'apt-get update' afterwards?

2: How can i use the apt:ppa module to add the docker-ce [repository](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)?
this is done with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

But how would i use the apt::ppa to include distribution and release?

This is the whole puppet block:

```
class docker {

  $prerequisites = ['apt-transport-https', 'ca-certificates', 'curl']
  package { $prerequisites: ensure => installed}

  apt::key { 'docker-ce':
    ensure    => present,
    id        => '9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88',
    options   => 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg',
  }

  apt::ppa {''}

  package {'docker-ce': ensure  => installed}
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ended up using the apt module with apt::source, hardcoded release because i know all my systems will run it.

```
class docker {
  include apt

  $prerequisites = ['apt-transport-https', 'ca-certificates']
  package { $prerequisites: ensure => installed} ->

  apt::key { 'docker-ce':
     ensure    => present,
     id        => '9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88',
     options   => 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg',
  } ->

  apt::source {'docker-ce':
     location  => 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu',
     release   => 'xenial'
  } ->

  exec { 'apt-get-update':
     command   => '/usr/bin/apt-get update'
  } ->

  package {'docker-ce': ensure  => installed}
}
```

Comment: There's an ["approved" module](https://forge.puppet.com/garethr/docker) 
 for installing docker using Puppet. May be worth trying that first. If not, it's open source, you can see [how they do it](https://github.com/garethr/garethr-docker/blob/master/manifests/install.pp) on Github.

Comment: Doesnt look like it installs docker-ce, but i will look at how they do it at see if i can extract some information from it. thanks @R0MANARMY

Comment: It definitely installs docker-ce.

Comment: @MattSchuchard indeed it does. I ended up using the apt module with apt::source

Comment: for ubuntu64 i had to add [arch=amd64] to 'location' url in apt::source, otherwise it kept telling me that 'docker-ce' package was not found

Comment: *AND* release => 'xenial stable'

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'm installing this:

```
  apt::key { '9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88':
    source => 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg',
  } ->
  apt::source { 'docker-ce':
    architecture => 'amd64',
    location     => 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu',
    repos        => 'stable',
    release      => $::lsbdistcodename,
  } ->
  package { 'docker-ce':
    ensure  => 'latest',
    require => Exec['apt_update'],
  }
```